# Azure Devops max number of variables in builds and releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've found some docs with resources limitation in Azure DevOps:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/service-limits?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops

But I cannot find any info about limitation of variables number in builds and releases. Can anyone share this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot find any info about limitation of variables number in
>   builds and releases. Can anyone share this info?

Sorry but I'm afraid there's no any official document states the related info about the limitation of the maximum number of variables in pipeline.

As I know, there's no limitation of variables when configuring pipelines if we're in normal situations. It means you won't actually meet the limitation in normal and most situations.

**In addition:** I've tested at least 60 variables are supported in pipelines and it's not recommended to define too many variables in build/release pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a bug in Azure DevOps that can give the impression that no further variables can be added. But I have successfully added well over 130 variables, therefore I doubt that there is a limit